# set a field read-only when checkbox enabled

Tags: inputcheckboxes

I've created a VF page and got a input text field referring a campaign field and a checkbox which **is not referenced** to any object field. So I need help on writing js to disable and enabled the text field when the checbox is checked/unchecked.

any help on this please?

Answer (score 1):

Visualforce allows you to use html tags, so you could use something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="var theTextBox = document.getElementById('{!$Component.theId}'); theTextBox.disabled = theTextBox.disabled ? false : true;" />
```

Just make sure to switch `theId` with the actual id of the visualforce inputField component in your page. A good reference on how to refer to Visualforce Ids in javascript can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_component.htm).